# How to harden external hard disk against ransomware

Tags: windows, backup, external-hard-drive

With the basic consumer backup setup that uses a **permanently connected** external hard drive to store the backup, with simple backup software or a robocopy script, what can be done to protect the disk against ransomware?

I mean anything beyond protecting the PC against viruses in general.

Comment: you could try to restrict write (and perhaps read) access to the disk to a single user account (one you never use) and run your backup software as that user. that would prevent your normal user from being able to encrypt the contents of the disk, unless the ransomware obtained admin in UAC. One of the main appeals of Ransomware to cyber criminals is that it is a no-root exploit. it only needs to encrypt the data the user has access to to achieve their end.

Comment: backup the "permenentaly connected" external to a not permenentally connected external. connect it to sync it up , and most times have it just sitting there with 90+% the same data, but not connected.  Tis better to have the ability to recover up to your last week, 2 weeks, or month , than to less than that.

Comment: Frank's comment should be the answer. It's not only a feasible option, it's actually *the only* option (if we exclude marginal exotics such as custom formatted drives accessible only through backup software).

Comment: @FrankThomas I agree with Angstrom, I'll accept it if you post it.

Comment: isn't it simpler to disable java in your browser?

Comment: @user531772 "I mean anything beyond protecting the PC against viruses in general"

Comment: To the people who vote to close as "too broad": So far there has only been one suggestion that matches the criteria of the question. If you know of a broad range of better answers, please post one of them.